# Defining variable for output location based on feature class attribute?

Tags: arcpy, python

I'm pretty new to python. I have a feature class of points (Points_Layer) that covers the state and a feature class of municipal boundaries (Municipalities).

My script is going to loop through each municipality in the Municipalities layer. First the script will use the Select Layer by Location tool (overlap_type = intersect) to select points from "Points_Layer" within the municipality then Feature Class to Feature Class to create a layer of the selected features. It will loop through every municipality in the state. I want to save the output to different geodatabases/feature datasets based on attributes from the Municipalities layer (county name and municipal code).

My files are set up like this:

```
C:\Counties\
    CountyA.gdb
        Town1_0001
        Town2_0002
    CountyB.gdb
        Town3_0101
        Town4_0102
        Town5_0103
```

The Municipalities layer has a "County" field that has the name of the county the municipality is in, and a "Muni_Code" field that has the 4 digit municipal code. To define the output location my plan is to do something like:

```
outLocation = os.path.join(r'C:\Counties', gdbName, FDName)
```

I just don't know how to define gdbName and FDName. I'm thinking that arcpy.SearchCursor, the List function (eg arcpy.ListGeodatabases), or even arcpy.da.Walk would be useful but I'm not sure how to use them in this case. I'm especially struggling with how to get FDName - I need to match the Muni_Code field to the last 4 characters of the FDs. The gdbName should be easier because the name of the gdb exactly matches the "County" field.

Comment: See this example how to traverse through gdbs and feature classes: [Storing points from multiple GDBs as object](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333663/storing-points-from-multiple-gdbs-as-object/333665#333665). Then use **da**.SearchCursor to read attributes

Comment: How are you planning to handle a point feature that intersects a muni that intersects more than one county?

Comment: @artwork21 it would go in both counties. I'll edit my post to have more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through your muni feature class with the search cursor and select points by its geometry. The tricky part is creating the proper geodatabases and datasets. Check for gdb existence with `arcpy.Exists` and datasets with `arcpy.ListDatasets`. Something like this:

```
#point fc
pntFc = r"C:\your\point.gdb\featurecalss"
#municipalities fc
polyFc = r"C:\your\muni.gdb\featurecalss"
#county field name
cntyFld = "County"
#muni code field
muniFld = "Muni_Code"
#folder to house geodatabases
folder = r"C:\Counties"

import arcpy
import os


#make feature layer of points for selection
pntLyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (pntFc, "lyr") [0]

#crete int variable for dataset number
town = 0

#get spatial reference for dataset
sr = arcpy.Describe (pntFc).spatialReference

#search cursor of munis with county, muni, and shape (geometry) fields
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (polyFc, [cntyFld, muniFld, "SHAPE@"]) as curs:
    for cnty, muni, geom in curs:

        ####setting up gdb and data sets
        #check for geodatabase
        gdb = os.path.join (folder, "{}.gdb".format (cnty))
        if not arcpy.Exists (gdb):
            #create geodatabase
            gdb = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management (folder, "{}.gdb".format (cnty)) [0]
        #set env to gdb
        arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
        #list datasets
        try:
            #check for dataset
            ds = arcpy.ListDatasets ("*{}".format (muni)) [0]
            ds = os.path.join (gdb, ds)
        except IndexError: #dataset doesn't exist
            town += 1
            #create dataset
            ds = arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management (gdb, "Town{}_{}".format (town, muni), sr) [0]

        ####selecting points and exporting
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management (pntLyr, "", geom)
        ###naming convention of output - you can change this up
        outFc = arcpy.CreateUnqiueName ("Points", ds)
        #copy features
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management (pntLyr, outFc)
```